# Power connecter with Acer extensa lap top computer

Tags: laptop, charger

The power charger connection is intermitant have to get it just right in order to charge the computer. Can this be replaced and is it expensive?

Answer (score 1):

Laptop chargers can be replaced for between $30 and $60. They are commonly found on [eBay,](http://www.ebay.com) [Top Mic,](http://www.topmic.com/laptop-ac-adapter-power-supply-charger-and-power-cord--acer-laptop-battery-charger-ac-adapter-cord.html) etc. On Top Mic, they come with a lifetime warranty and free shipping, so that seems like the safest bet.

**Edit:**

The Acer  website does not sell replacement power cords for the laptop you have, so a third party solution seems to be the only option available.